# Need help identifying sets!

Tags: piece-information, set-identification, set-database

So...my son is 9 years old. Up until this year, he has been receiving Lego sets since he was about 6 but would rip them open, build the guys and then not finish the set. Now he is really unto them finally and I'm trying to piece back together his older sets so he can finish them. Alot of them are still in bags but some aren't. I'm going to post pics of the intact bags I have and would love help identifying them so I can try to find the instructions instead of throwing away tons of $$$. All of them are newer than 5 years...I have a couple that are mega blox and will post those too[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Minifigures would make it much easier to identify sets, if that is possible.

Comment: Most of these are from Minecraft sets. The fact that the numbering goes as high as bag 6 indicates some of these are large sets. The 6th picture seems to show set 21116 The Mine.

Comment: The rest are probably from 1 or more large Minecraft sets. Only hard the point out which one. Most are pointing out to https://brickset.com/sets/21116-1/Crafting-Box

Answer (score 3):

Last photo unnumbered bag: [76037-1: Rhino and Sandman Super Villain Team-up](https://brickset.com/sets/76037-1/Rhino-and-Sandman-Super-Villain-Team-up)

Answer (score 2):

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJDbb.jpg) is also pointing to Minecraft. I focused on a "specific" piece which is part [6089103](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6089103) and result being an arc.
It's contained in 12 sets.

Then combining with the [basic 2*4 orange brick](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4153827/theme-Minecraft), we got 7 sets.

I found [these instructions for bag 5 (page 2)](https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/6116567.pdf), and seems to be the one (has the skeleton arms, the single round grey parts, orange/blue brick in it...)

So I'd tend to say that's [21118-1: The Mine](https://brickset.com/sets/21118-1/The-Mine)
Check the instructions maybe others bags can match that box.

[@Phil B.](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/4181/phil-b) [tends also to say that the 6th image is from that set](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9666/need-help-identifying-sets/9671#comment11401_9666).